# Selection of rows in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame say(df) in which columns are **state** , **city** , **pincode**.

I can select all the rows for particular city in a state like this.

```
requiredState = 'ABC'
requiredCity  = 'XYZ'

newDf = df[ (df['city']== requiredCity) & (df['state']==requiredState) ]
```

Now I want to select all the rows for all cities of **a state**.

So this can be done by simply removing the city condition like:

```
newDf = df[ (df['state'] == requiredState) ]
```

This will give me all the cities of a state.

My question is, Is there some method in which 
I need not to remove the city condition and it will result to all the cities in a state?

i.e. something like

```
requiredCity = ALL
nDf = df[ (df['city']== requiredCity) & (df['state']==requiredState) ]
```

or Can we pass a list of required cities instead of ALL?

i.e.

```
requiredCity = ['city1','city2']
```

Comment: thank you very much for edit.

Comment: your welcome Jezrael. Keep sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) but `requiredCity` has to be in `list`, so is possible add new condition chained with `|` (or) of original condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city':list('abcdef'),
                   'pincode':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'state':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
  city  pincode state
0    a        4     a
1    b        5     a
2    c        4     a
3    d        5     b
4    e        5     b
5    f        4     b


requiredState = 'a'
requiredCity = ['ALL']

m1 = ('ALL' in requiredCity) | (df['city'].isin(requiredCity))
m2 = (df['state']==requiredState)
newDf = df[m1 & m2]
print (newDf)
  city  pincode state
0    a        4     a
1    b        5     a
2    c        4     a
```

---

```
requiredState = 'a'
requiredCity = ['a','c']

m1 = ('ALL' in requiredCity) | (df['city'].isin(requiredCity))
m2 = (df['state']==requiredState)
newDf = df[m1 & m2]
print (newDf)
  city  pincode state
0    a        4     a
2    c        4     a
```

---

```
requiredState = 'a'
requiredCity = ['a']

m1 = ('ALL' in requiredCity) | (df['city'].isin(requiredCity))
m2 = (df['state']==requiredState)
newDf = df[m1 & m2]
print (newDf)
  city  pincode state
0    a        4     a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 requiredCity = ['city1', 'city2']
 df[(df['city'].apply(lambda x : x in requiredCity)) & (df['state'] == requiredState)]
```